# How do I fix errors when packaging a Pixel Streaming project?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-20.04, unreal-engine5

How do I fix errors when packaging a Pixel Streaming project?

https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.2/en-US/getting-started-with-pixel-streaming-in-unreal-engine/

Following the above, I got to 1.3 Package your Project for Windows. From the main menu in the Unreal Editor, choose Files > Package Project > Windows (64-bit).
But here I get an error.

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Linux): RunUAT ERROR: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully. Exited with code: 134

PackagingResults: Error: AutomationTool was unable to run successfully. Exited with code: 134

PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error
```

How can this be resolved? Not packaged.

Error log:

```
Log started at 07/02/2023 14:53:52 (2023-07-02T05:53:52Z)
Compile module: FreeType2
Compile module: HarfBuzz
Compile module: Nanosvg
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-SlateCore.so.link.sh
Compile module: DeveloperSettings
Module 'DeveloperSettings' using unity build mode
Module 'DeveloperSettings' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/CoreUObject/SharedPCH.CoreUObject.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-DeveloperSettings.so.link.sh
Compile module: Slate
Module 'Slate' using unity build mode
Module 'Slate' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/CoreUObject/SharedPCH.CoreUObject.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Compile module: SDL2
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-Slate.so.link.sh
Compile module: DirectoryWatcher
Module 'DirectoryWatcher' using unity build mode
Module 'DirectoryWatcher' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Core/SharedPCH.Core.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-DirectoryWatcher.so.link.sh
Compile module: SlateFileDialogs
Module 'SlateFileDialogs' using unity build mode
Module 'SlateFileDialogs' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Slate/SharedPCH.Slate.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-SlateFileDialogs.so.link.sh
Compile module: DesktopPlatform
Module 'DesktopPlatform' using unity build mode
Module 'DesktopPlatform' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Core/SharedPCH.Core.ShadowErrors.TypeCastErrors.h.gch'
Compile module: SDL2
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-DesktopPlatform.so.link.sh
Compile module: DeveloperToolSettings
Module 'DeveloperToolSettings' using unity build mode
Module 'DeveloperToolSettings' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/CoreUObject/SharedPCH.CoreUObject.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-DeveloperToolSettings.so.link.sh
Compile module: SandboxFile
Module 'SandboxFile' not using unity build mode (module with fewer than 2 source files)
Module 'SandboxFile' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Core/SharedPCH.Core.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-SandboxFile.so.link.sh
Compile module: IoStoreUtilities
Module 'IoStoreUtilities' using unity build mode
Module 'IoStoreUtilities' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/CoreUObject/SharedPCH.CoreUObject.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Compile module: libcurl
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-IoStoreUtilities.so.link.sh
Compile module: MessageLog
Module 'MessageLog' using unity build mode
Module 'MessageLog' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Slate/SharedPCH.Slate.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-MessageLog.so.link.sh
Compile module: SourceControl
Module 'SourceControl' using unity build mode
Module 'SourceControl' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Slate/SharedPCH.Slate.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-SourceControl.so.link.sh
Compile module: Virtualization
Module 'Virtualization' using unity build mode
Module 'Virtualization' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/CoreUObject/SharedPCH.CoreUObject.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-Virtualization.so.link.sh
Compile module: PakFileUtilities
Module 'PakFileUtilities' using unity build mode
Module 'PakFileUtilities' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Core/SharedPCH.Core.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-PakFileUtilities.so.link.sh
Compile module: PerforceSourceControl
Module 'PerforceSourceControl' using unity build mode
Module 'PerforceSourceControl' uses PCH '/home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Slate/SharedPCH.Slate.ShadowErrors.h.gch'
Compile module: Perforce
Creating link script: /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Linux/B4D820EA/UnrealPak/Development/Link-libUnrealPak-PerforceSourceControl.so.link.sh
Writing manifest to /home/iplslam/UnrealEngine/Engine/Intermediate/Build/Manifest.xml
Target is up to date
Total execution time: 2.17 seconds
```

UE version:5.11
OS: ubuntu 20.04